# Same start command, different results

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file containing

```
start "" "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=vi&text=I%20am%20Mina.%0AI%20am%20a%20student."
```

Gives the incorrect answer

```
I0am0Mina.starttransAI0am0a0student.
```

But starting the same from the command line, it gives the correct answer

```
I am Mina.
I am a student.
```

Anyone can tell me what the batch file does`?

Thanks

Comment: In a [tag:batch-file], as opposed to the [tag:command-prompt], _([tag:cmd])_, you need to double your **`%`** characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `start "" "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=vi&text=I%%20am%%20Mina.%%0AI%%20am%%20a%%20student."`. You need to add an extra `%` to escape a `%` percent sign.